# PostgreSQL still able to make connection after updating UFW

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, networking, postgresql-9.4, ufw

I am trying to test how an application handles network instability. The client application makes connections and runs queries on a database server. To simulate network instability, I am trying to make ufw rules to deny traffic going out while the client application makes a connection to the database server. I start up the application and it is able to run queries on the database. I then update the UFW rules. The following two rules are the top 2 rules.

[ 1] 5432/udp                   DENY OUT    Anywhere (out)

[ 2] 5432/tcp                   DENY OUT    Anywhere (out)

After the ufw rules have been updated, the client is still able to make calls the the database server. However, If I reboot the client application it is then unable to make a connection to the database server.

Does anyone know why this is occurring? Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do? Any help would be much appreciated.

More Details: The client application is using postgresql-9.4-1207.jdbc4 to connect to the database. The database is running postgresql 9.4.5.

Answer (score 1):

UFW comes with some default configuration options in place. On my Ubuntu server they are located in /etc/ufw. In the before.rules file there are two rules ...

```
#-A ufw-before-input -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
#-A ufw-before-output -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

... that allow in established connections. Since these rules are read in before the user specified rules, they take precidence. I commented out these two lines in the configuration file and my issue is resolved.

However, the comment above these two lines reads "# quickly process packets for which we already have a connection". Not sure what kind of performance impact this would have, but I am not particularly concerned about that in my case. This might be a concern for someone else though.